# Why React DRF app deploying with Heroku gives Invalid HTTP_HOST header error?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, django-rest-framework

I am trying to deploy my first React DRF app with Heroku. It has been deployed successfully(Under View release log in Heroku Dashboard, It is showing No migrations to apply). But when I tried to access the site it gives me error stating

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'mySite-test.herokuapp.com'. You may need to add 'mySite-test.herokuapp.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

Although I have added the same to settings.py. I am using gunicorn version 19.9.0 and whitenoise version 4.1.3 .

What I have done so far

```
import os
import django_heroku

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['http://127.0.0.1:8000/', 'https://mySite-test.herokuapp.com/']


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'personal_blog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'personal_blog.wsgi.application'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static'),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

wsgi.py

```
import os
from whitenoise import WhiteNoise
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'personal_blog.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = WhiteNoise(application, root='build/static')
```

and in project root urls.py

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('accounts.api.urls')),
    re_path('.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))

]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Here is my folder structure

[image]

Someone please point me out what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Main issue was with Python version. After upgrading python from 3.7.1 to 3.7.4 and lillte modification in settings.py to

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '.herokuapp.com']

All working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You should not include the http protocol in your allowed hosts, it should only be the domain name, and possibly the port, although I’m not entirely sure.

Change

```
 ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['http://127.0.0.1:8000/', 'https://mySite-test.herokuapp.com/']
```

to

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'mySite-test.herokuapp.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

Heroku's domain service is providing this protection.
so you don't allow your localhost.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mySite-test.herokuapp.com']
```